# Conditional visibility of a custom property in visual WebPart SharePoint

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, web-parts

I am editing some feature of a SharePoint visual webPart and I need to add on custom text box property which needs to be appeared if user choose one specific value from another drop down property. I am not sure which attribute I can add to the new text property to make it conditional visible.

```
If (Action.toString()=="Custom")
 {
    visibility = true
 }
```

I am not sure I need to work around webBrowsable (true) ?
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide in your post the code you are working with. Thank you.